# How to set Relative background color like half circle?

Tags: android, layout

I create relative layout i want to set background color like half circle on top . i given like display below.please help me .[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: i don't know  how to reach there.

Comment: then why are you asking questions here?

Comment: use a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have created following xml drawable you can use this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
    android:left="-150dp"
    android:right="-150dp"
    android:top="-200dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#C72C2F" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Just copy and paste it in half_circle.xml in DRAWABLE folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
 <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="190dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="190dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
 <padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />
 <stroke
    android:width="0dp" />
 <gradient
    android:startColor="#2196f3"
    android:endColor= "#2196f3"
    android:angle="90" />
 </shape>
```

Use like this

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="48"
        android:background="@drawable/half_filled_circle">
     </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) image and set it to the background. The patch (the part that is stretchable) would be set to just below the end of the half circle.

Comment: this not image only relativelayout background color .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) specifying [paint.setStyle(FILL)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStyle(android.graphics.Paint.Style)) then in your view's [onDraw(Canvas c)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) you can draw a path using [canvas.drawPath(path,paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint)).

or

You can define a [LayerList Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) containing two [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) in the following order

1. Create a Rectangle
2. Create an oval

You are done now set this Layer list drawable to any view or layout as background.

or

You can have a nine patch image.